# Flutter image version issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I have just upgraded my flutter version and now I am facing the following issue when I get the packages in pubsec.yml file:

> > Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on image 2.1.4 and Instant_Feedback depends on image ^2.1.9, flutter_test from sdk is forbidden.
>
> So, because Instant_Feedback depends on flutter_test any from sdk,
>   version solving failed. pub get failed (1; So, because
>   Instant_Feedback depends on flutter_test any from sdk, version solving
>   failed.)

My pubsec.yml file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.4+8
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.3
  flutter_crashlytics: ^1.0.0
  firebase_core: ^0.4.2+1
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  device_calendar: ^1.0.0+2
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.11
  auto_size_text: ^2.1.0
  flutter_expandable_menu: ^0.0.1
  webview_flutter: ^0.3.17
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.1.1+1
  get_it: 2.1.0
  bloc: ^0.15.0
  flutter_bloc: 0.21.0
  equatable: 0.5.1
  rflutter_alert: ^1.0.3
  expandable: ^3.0.1
  connectivity: ^0.4.6
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.1
  flutter_email_sender: ^2.2.1
  mockito: 4.1.1
  flutter_secure_storage: ^3.3.1+1
  image_picker: ^0.6.2+2
  async: any
  image: ^2.1.10
  image_crop: ^0.3.1
  flutter_cache_manager: ^1.1.3
  circular_profile_avatar: ^1.0.3
  package_info: ^0.4.0+12
  flutter_local_notifications: ^0.8.4+3
  flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.10
  url_launcher: ^5.2.7
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_cupertino_localizations: ^1.0.1


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_driver:
    sdk: flutter
  test: any

  ozzie: 2.0.1
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - lib/app/assets/images/
    - lib/app/assets/flags/
    - lang/en.json
    - lang/de.json
```

Comment: Maybe this article could help https://iirokrankka.com/2018/08/28/resolving-dart-package-version-conflicts/

Comment: I would advise you to start slowly updating the versions of the packages that have incompatibility. There is no straight answer anyone can give you for this. You have to do it on your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on image 2.1.4 and Instant_Feedback depends on image ^2.1.9, flutter_test from sdk is forbidden.

I faced the same issue. Couldn't find the specific reason for the flutter_test depending on a specific version of this image library. Maybe it's an issue from the flutter side. So here are some workaround solutions:

1. comment out the flutter_test dev_dependency.

   `dev_dependencies:
    #    flutter_test:
    #        sdk: flutter`
2. set the required version.

   Instead of 2.1.12, I set the Image package version to 2.1.4 (as requested in the error message)

   `image: ^2.1.4`
3. If more than one packages versions are noncompatible to each other, and you don't know their exact compatible version, you can find it by setting both the conflicting dependencies to `any`,  e.g.

   `flutter_crashlytics: any
    firebase_core: any`

   This will automatically figure out the compatible package version. Check these new compatible versions in `pubspec.lock` file, which will be auto-generated by running `flutter package get`.

   `# Generated by pub
    # See https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/glossary#lockfile
    packages:
      flutter_crashlytics:
        ...
        version: "1.0.0" 
      firebase_core:
        ...
        version: "0.4.2+1"`

   Replace `any` with those correct versions.

   `flutter_crashlytics: 1.0.0
    firebase_core: 0.4.2+1`

Note: You should never leave your versions as `any`